# Not able to pass object in node route and render a page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on a `node.js`project with `express.js`. I run a route and render ejs page and pass `team` object with it. When I do a `console.log(team)` it displays the team details but it gives `undefined` value for `<%= team.member.name %>` although it exists. How can I resolve this. I am attaching screenshot of `console.log(team)` and my ejs code too. Please help [This is the embedded screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBHFU.png)

My ejs file is:

```html
<% include ./partials/header%>
<% console.log("yup"+team)%>
          <table class="table-striped table table-bordered">
            <tr class="thead-dark">
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Year</th>
              <th>Skills</th>
              <th>Leader</th>
            </tr>
                <% for(i = 0; i < team.members.length; i++){
                var member = team.members[i];%>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= member.name %></td>
                  <td><%= member.year %></td>
                  <td>
                    <ul>
                        <% for(var i = 0; i < member.skills.length; i++){ %>
                          <li>
                            <%= member.skills[i];%>
                          </li>
                          <% } %>
                    </ul> 
                  </td>
                  <td><% if(member.isLeader) { %>
                   Yes
                   <% } else { %>
                   No
                   <% } %>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  <% } %>
          </table>   
<% include ./partials/footer%>
```

and my route code is:

```js
router.get("/:id/view/:challengeid/:username", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  Mentor.findById(req.params.id, function(err, mentor){
    mentor.mentorChallenges.forEach(function(chall){
      var k = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < chall.applicants.length; i ++){
        if(chall.applicants[i] == req.params.username){
          k = 1;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(k === 1){
        Team.find({username: req.params.username}, function(err, team){
          res.render("teamDetails", {team: team});
        });
      }
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is a problem in your `for` loop. Did you try `forEach` loop?
Try to use this:

```
    <% team.members.forEach(member => { %>
           <tr>
              <td><%= member.name %></td>
              <td><%= member.year %></td>
              <td>
                 <ul>
                    <% member.skills.forEach(skill => { %>
                       <li>
                          <%= skill%>
                       </li>
                     <% }); %>
                  </ul> 
               </td>
               <td><% if(member.isLeader) { %>
                  Yes
                   <% } else { %>
                  No
                   <% } %>
               </td>
          </tr>
    <% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if (typeof team === "undefined" ) { %> 
// do smth
<%} else {%>
// do smth
<%}%>
```

According to some conditions, you are getting `team` as `undefined`, it means while you are making `GET` request, nothing is being sent to your `ejs` file, but in some conditions, you are getting `team` as `defined`, So you have to implicitly implement both cases

Comment: Yeah, there are many ways to solve the problem, but it is great that you have solved it :)